# не получается настроить Apache2

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Не получается настроить. Ошибка не даёт подняться серверу:

```
(2)No such file or directory: AH00089: Couldn't start ErrorLog process '/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/apache2/uccht.error.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400'.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Не смог нагуглить ответа.

Comment: Проверьте может ли пользователь www-data создавать файлы в папке /var/log/apache2/

Comment: Нет, проблема не в этом.

Comment: В 14.04 эта прога лежит в `/usr/bin` (у тебя в ошибке sbin) в составе пакета `apache2-utils`. Может в этом проблема?

Comment: Да, проблема была в этом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конфигурация перенес со старого сервера, там адрес неправильный был. Изменение с sbin на bin помогло

Comment: надеюсь @donRumata оформит это как ответ, чтобы заплюсовать можно было